# CSS background image doesn't display in Chrome when the div height is greater than the height of the image

Tags: css, google-chrome

A site I inherited uses a sprite for some design based images. The sprite is 28px tall. Recently it began that when the site is viewed in Chrome, the sprite does not display on the elements when the height of the container with a background is > 28px.

I was able to reproduce this using the below snippet.

It's especially odd that if i create a narrower image, I don't have this problem. The break point seems to be width: 16384px or 2^14.

```css
.outer {
  width: 1000px;
  background-color: skyblue;
}

.bg {
  background: url('https://i.imgur.com/DEV7k42.png');
}
```

```html
<div class='outer'>
  <div class='bg'>
    <div style='height:28px'>
       See this nice background?
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='outer'>
  <div class='bg'>
    <div style='height: 29px;'>
        No background here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This uses an image that is 16384px wide:

```css
.outer {
  width: 1000px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.bg {
  background: url('https://i.imgur.com/1vd6POs.png');
}
```

```html
<div class='outer'>
  <div class='bg'>
    <div style='height: 29px;'>
      this image is 13684px wide
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This uses an image that is 16385px wide:

```css
.outer {
  width: 1000px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.bg {
  background: url('https://i.imgur.com/KV0uyia.png');
}
```

```html
<div class='outer'>
  <div class='bg'>
    <div style='height: 29px;'>
       This uses an image that is 16385px wide
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Could this be a bug? I did a quick google search and could not find anything to indicate there is a hard limit on the dimensions of an image.

Comment: I'm on Chrome and I can always see the background image

Comment: What version of chrome?

Comment: I'm at 61.0.3163.91 64Bit

Comment: That looks to be the beta channel - https://chromereleases.googleblog.com/ . Maybe this was fixed - i'm on 60.0.3112.113 (Official Build) (64-bit) and have gotten the complaint from a number of users

Comment: Beta channel is v62 at the moment, I'm on the stable channel.

Comment: Stable channel on windows is v60 per the above link. What is your OS? I may need to update the question.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome_version_history) the current stable release for Windows, Mac and Linux is 61. Your link seems to refer to Chrome OS?

Comment: Thanks for the correction- I re-installed chrome using the latest installer and am now on v61 and still have the issue...  What is your OS? I may need to update the question.

Comment: I am using Windows 10 Version 1703 Build 15063.608. Seems to be a pretty strange issue

Comment: Thanks for all the info. I'm using the same OS / Build (15063.608) and browser version (Version 61.0.3163.91 (Official Build) (64-bit)) and don't know how to explain the difference in behavior

Answer (score 0):

I simplified the structure and placed the `bg image` and `color` on the outer `div`. Seems to work:

```css
.outer {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 28px;
  background: url('https://i.imgur.com/DEV7k42.png');
  background-color: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<div class='outer'>
  <div style='height:28px'>
    See this nice background?
  </div>
</div>

<div class='outer'>
  <div style='height: 29px;'>
    No background here
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't fix the issue. You are setting the height of the outer container to 28px which as I said is not broken. If you remove the height: 28px to the outer container it breaks again.

Comment: Understood. This is strange behavior indeed. If you set the height of the second div to 28px than it works.